# Delegation Denied for "myemail@mydomain.com" When I try to send emails through the Gmail API using my Google service account

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, gmail-api, google-workspace

I am trying to use the latest Gmail API "Google.Apis.Gmail.v1 (1.54.0.2356)" in .Net Framework to send emails. I have a Google Workspace account and I am trying to use my Service Account to impersonate as one of the emails in my workspace account to send emails. I have domain-wide delegation enabled for my service account in Google workspace. I have delegate-emails setting enabled in my Workspace Gmail Application settings as well. I have added all Gmail scopes to my application registered on Google Workspace as well.

My code is as follows:

```
    static string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.GmailSend, GmailService.Scope.GmailInsert, GmailService.Scope.GmailLabels,
    GmailService.Scope.GmailMetadata, GmailService.Scope.GmailModify, GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly, GmailService.Scope.GmailSettingsBasic,
    GmailService.Scope.GmailSettingsSharing, GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom, GmailService.Scope.GmailAddonsCurrentActionCompose, GmailService.Scope.GmailAddonsCurrentMessageAction,
    GmailService.Scope.GmailAddonsCurrentMessageMetadata, GmailService.Scope.GmailAddonsCurrentMessageReadonly, GmailService.Scope.GmailMetadata };

    public static GmailService GmailAccess { get; set; }

    public static BaseClientService.Initializer GetConfiguration(string[] scopeList)
    {
        CustomServiceAccountCredentials creds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomServiceAccountCredentials>(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("myServiceAccountCreds.json"));
        return new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(creds.ClientEmail)
            {
                Scopes = scopeList,
                ProjectId = creds.ProjectId,
                KeyId = "myKeyID",
                User = "emailIwantToImpersonate@myDomain.com"
            }.FromPrivateKey(creds.PrivateKey))
        };
    }

    public static void GainGmailAccess()
    {
        GmailAccess = new GmailService(
            GetConfiguration(Scopes)
        );
    }

   //Just a class I made to make it easier to fetch details from the service account credentials file
    public class CustomServiceAccountCredentials
    {
        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("project_id")]
        public string ProjectId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("private_key_id")]
        public string PrivateKeyId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("private_key")]
        public string PrivateKey { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("client_email")]
        public string ClientEmail { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("client_id")]
        public string ClientId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("auth_uri")]
        public Uri AuthUri { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("token_uri")]
        public Uri TokenUri { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("auth_provider_x509_cert_url")]
        public Uri AuthProviderX509CertUrl { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("client_x509_cert_url")]
        public Uri ClientX509CertUrl { get; set; }
    }
```

And I try to send my email with the following code:

```
        GainGmailAccess();
        var result = GmailAccess.Users.Messages.Send(myMsg, recipient).Execute();
```

But I end up with the following error in the line where I execute the request:

> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
> Delegation denied for emailIwantToImpersonate@myDomain.com [403]
> Errors [
> Message[Delegation denied for emailIwantToImpersonate@myDomain.com] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global]
> ]

Even the following approach gave the same error:

```
        GoogleCredential credential = null;
        using (var stream =
           new FileStream("myServiceAccountCreds.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(Scopes)
          .CreateWithUser("emailIwantToImpersonate@myDomain.com");
        }
        var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "MyAppName"
        });
        var result = service.Users.Messages.Send(msg, recipient).Execute();
```

I want to confirm that the email I want to impersonate does, in fact, exist in my workspace account. I know very few scopes are required to achieve what I want to but I added all these for testing purposes. I even added my Google Developer Console application (which has this service account) to my Workspace third party apps and gave it full permissions. Something I wanted to point out is that the following requests are however executing perfectly:

```
        Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Delegate delReq = new Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Delegate();
        delReq.DelegateEmail = "anotherEmailInMyWorkspace@myDomain.com";
        var result2 = GmailAccess.Users.Settings.Delegates.Create(delReq, "me").Execute(); //no errors here
```

And

```
        Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.SendAs snAs = new Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.SendAs();
        snAs.DisplayName = "Some Display Name";
        snAs.SendAsEmail = "anotherEmailInMyWorkspace@myDomain.com";
        var result3 = GmailAccess.Users.Settings.SendAs.Create(snAs, "me").Execute(); //no errors here
```

I even gave all relevant roles to these email accounts in the Developer Console service account settings. Where is the problem stemming from?

Comment: Yes, struggling with the same issue. Following

Answer (score 1):

Delegation denied for emailIwantToImpersonate@myDomain.com implies to me that you have not properly set up service account delegation in your workspace account have the admin check that the service account is in fact allowed to delegate as emailIwantToImpersonate@myDomain.com

Your code looks similar to the code i have here.

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;

using System;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string Base64Encode(string plainText)
        {
            var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
            return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
        }

    public static void SendMail()
    {
        try
        {
            string ApplicationName = "Gmail API .NET Quickstart";
            const string serviceAccount = "Serviceaccount@email";

            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"c:\serviceaccount.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            var gsuiteUser = "user@gsuiteuser.com";

            var serviceAccountCredentialInitializer = new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccount)
            {
                User = gsuiteUser,
                Scopes = new[] { GmailService.Scope.GmailSend, GmailService.Scope.GmailLabels }

            }.FromCertificate(certificate);

            var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(serviceAccountCredentialInitializer);
            if (!credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Access token failed.");

            var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("user@gsuiteuser.com");
            mailMessage.To.Add("auser@hotmail.com");
            mailMessage.ReplyToList.Add("user@gsuiteuser.com");
            mailMessage.Subject = "test";
            mailMessage.Body = "<h1>sdf</h1>";
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

            //foreach (System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment in email.Attachments)
            //{
            //    mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            //}

            var mimeMessage = MimeKit.MimeMessage.CreateFromMailMessage(mailMessage);

            var gmailMessage = new Message
            {
                Raw = Base64Encode(mimeMessage.ToString())
            };

            Message message1 = new Message();
            UsersResource.MessagesResource.SendRequest sendRequest = service.Users.Messages.Send(gmailMessage, "me");
            var s = sendRequest.Execute();


            Console.WriteLine("Message delivered!");
        }
        catch (Exception ep)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ep.ToString());
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        SendMail();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I am the admin of the workspace account. I have done two things on the workspace account: 1. Enabled domain wide delegation for my service account. 2. Enabled email delegation in Apps -> Gmail -> Settings. What else do you suggest I do?

Comment: What about authority to the user?  [delegate_domain-wide_authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account)